# DevTools not evaluating `$0` eagerly

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

After selecting an element, typing `$0` in the console doesn't give me preview of the result. It simply suggests from history. However, `document.querySelector` works fine. I'm using Edge `122.0.2365.92`.

[image: $0 not eager evaluated]
[image: $0. not providing helpful completions]
[image: document.querySelector works fine]

I expect devtools to eager evaluate the expression `$0`, preview the result and provide auto-completion based on that, just like `document.querySelector` would.

Also tried on Chrome `122.0.6261.131`, but it behaves the same as Edge.

Comment: Works for me, so it's either a bug that depends on some condition or the page defined its own global $0.

Comment: This issue is not site-specific, since `$0` doesn't eager-evaluate on all websites that I have tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue on latest version of both Edge and Chrome. However, for Edge, 121.0.2277.112 shows the eager evaluation for `$0` as expected.

Seems like a new issue on the latest version of Chromium, so I suggest you create a post on https://issues.chromium.org/.

Comment: Upgrading Chrome to `123.0.6312.59` indeed solves the problem. I assume that it is a bug in Chromium v122.

Comment: Updating Edge to `123.0.2420.53` solves the issue, too.